# $\sigma$-algebra containing all singletons

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the minimal $\sigma$–algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ which contains all singletons,i.e. one-element sets.
How can we describe the sets in $\mathcal{A}$ ?

Comment: Countable sets and their complements.

Answer (score 6):

The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is called the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra and is defined as follows:

$$\mathcal{A} := \{A \subseteq \mathbb{R}; \text{$A$ or $\mathbb{R} \backslash A$ is countable}\}.$$

Any $\sigma$-algebra containing all singletons has to contain all countable sets (since they can be written as a countable union of singletons) and their complements. Consequently,

$$\sigma(\{x\}; x \in \mathbb{R}\} \supseteq \mathcal{A}.$$

(Here the left-hand side denotes the minimal $\sigma$-algebra containing all singletons). On the other hand, it is not difficult to check that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and therefore

$$\sigma(\{x\}; x \in \mathbb{R}\} = \mathcal{A}.$$

Comment: Thank you. May I ask another question ? How can we describe measurable functions $f : (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{A}) → (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$–algebra.

Comment: @user43418 See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1478629/36150

Comment: So f must be constant function on a cocountable set ?

Comment: @user43418 Yes, that's correct...